# Is it safe to use Redis to store username and hashed passwords?

Tags: authentication, passwords

We are taking a look at using Redis for a Cache Aside pattern, and I am thinking, is it safe to store username and hashed passwords in Redis Cache? If yes, are there security issues with having a key structure like user:username?

Or for initial authentication / login using username and password, it is safer to perform direct DB read, and then store the Refresh Token instead in Redis?

Comment: It depends on what these username and passwords are being used for in your system and your system architecture. Without a lot more details about what your system does, I'd say, no it is not safe to do so.

Comment: The username and hashed passwords are for user logins. We are using Azure Redis and Azure Web App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem with using Redis if these conditions are both met:

- You trust your network between your application and your Redis instance, since [Redis lacks native support for SSL](https://redis.io/topics/encryption).
- Your Redis instance requires [authentication](https://redis.io/topics/security#authentication-feature).

The `user:username` key shouldn't be a problem neither, as long as you correctly handle username changes (creating the new cache entry, and deleting the old one).

Comment: Thanks Benoit! This is good to know. We are using Azure Redis which I think has SSL.

Comment: @Water: Indeed, [Azure Redis has support for SSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-faq#when-should-i-enable-the-non-ssl-port-for-connecting-to-redis)!